# create virtual directory in tomcat using jhipster

Tags: jhipster

i want to create virtual directory in tomcat to store uploaded attachments.To upload and download how to make use of it.How to configure the context for that to get access with servletcontext.getRealpath("") with the local path of the directory

Comment: This is not a jhipster question, you should ask spring-boot and/or tomcat. Regarding file upload JHipster 2.19.0 has added this feature but storing in the database.